# Delete line in txt file based on token

Tags: batch-file

I have txt file full_add where I need to find and delete lines based on tokens in full_delete. Then, save full_add with the rest of the lines.
This is sample data in each file:

full_add

```
Employee,800751,,1,9999,,,,,
Employee,800752,,1,9999,,,,,
Employee,800761,,1,9999,,,,,
Employee,800762,,1,9999,,,,,
```

full_delete

```
Employee,800751
Employee,800762
Employee,800742
```

final result in full_add after deliting

```
Employee,800752,,1,9999,,,,,
Employee,800761,,1,9999,,,,,
```

This is my idea:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims=," %i in (full_delete.txt) do find /v "%i" full_add.txt > full_add.txt
```

I get empty file full_add. If I change `>full_add.txt` for `>tmp.txt`, it works but only delete the last token line found. Thanks. Frank

Answer (score 2):

I think you should stay with your current change where you are outputting to `tmp.txt`, but in that case you will additionally need to remove the original `full_add.txt` and rename `tmp.txt` to `full_add.txt`:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims=," %i IN (full_delete.txt) DO (FIND /v "%i" < full_add.txt > tmp.txt & DEL full_add.txt & RENAME tmp.txt full_add.txt)
```

Or, instead, you can copy `tmp.txt` to `full_add.txt`, then remove `tmp.txt`:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims=," %i IN (full_delete.txt) DO (FIND /v "%i" < full_add.txt > tmp.txt & COPY tmp.txt full_add.txt & DEL tmp.txt)
```

**UPDATE**

I changed both FIND commands by adding `<` before `full_add.txt`.

Also, if you'd like to use the script in a batch file you should probably put the loop body commands on separate lines, like this (using the second script for an example):

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2 delims=," %i IN (full_delete.txt) DO (
  FIND /v "%i" < full_add.txt > tmp.txt
  COPY tmp.txt full_add.txt
  DEL tmp.txt
)
```

The indentation is entirely optional, of course.

Comment: I used the first approach and works fine, only it add 3 lines to the begining of the file: ---------- FULL_ADD_EMPLOYEE.TXT ---------- FULL_ADD_EMPLOYEE.TXT ---------- FULL_ADD_EMPLOYEE.TXT Also, if I put this in a batch (using %%i) it will give me syntax error. Thanks for your fast and excellent help. F.